# Use of glBindAttribLocation function in OpenGL ES

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-2.0

I dont get the use of `glBindAttribLocation` function in OpenGL ES 2.0

Can some one give me the full context ? Is it something like

```
g_pLightDir = g_pEffect10->GetVariableByName( "g_LightDir" )->AsVector();
```

in DirectX 10 ? Read online in various sites, but couldn't get the use of this function. Help needed..

Comment: Have you figured it out yourself and forgot about your question or do you still have some unclarities you may want to ask?

Answer (score 26):

This function let's you specify an attribute index for a user defined shader attribute (not for a uniform, as your code sample suggests), which you later use when refering to the attribute.

Say you have a vertex shader:

```
...
attribute vec4 vertex;     //or 'in vec4 vertex' in modern syntax
attribute vec3 normal;
...
```

You then can bind indices to those variables, with

```
glBindAttribLocation(program, 0, "vertex");
glBindAttribLocation(program, 1, "normal");
```

You can use whatever non-negative numbers you like (in a small range). Then when refering to these attributes you use their indices, e.g. in `glVertexAttribPointer` or `glEnableVertexAttribArray` functions.

But keep in mind that `glBindAttribLocation` has to be called before linking the program. You can also omit it. Then OpenGL automatically binds indices to all used attributes during linking, which can later be queried by `glGetAttribLocation`. But with `glBindAttribLocation` you can establish your own attribute index semantics and keep them consistent.

The newer GLSL versions even allow you to specify the attribute indices within the shader (using the `layout` syntax), removing the need for either `glBindAttribLocation` or `glGetAttribLocation`, but I'm not sure if this is supported in ES.

But my answer doesn't tell you more than those "various" sites you looked at or any good OpenGL/GLSL book, so if you still don't get it, delve a little deeper into the basics of GLSL.

Comment: If you don't use glBindAttribLocation is there a guaranteed default ordering like 0,1,2... or is a call to glGetAttribLocation required in this case?

Comment: @Jochen If you don't use `glBindAttribLocation` nothing is guaranteed and you need `glGetAttribLocation`. While a reasonable driver would probably use the first consecutive indices, nothing stops him from using any arbitrary numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I never used Direct X, but glBindAttribLocation is used to define the location for a Attribute in your shader, say you have this row in your shader:

```
attribute vec3 g_LightDir;
```

Then you can use glBindAttribLocation to set a location for that vec3, you must do this after you have attached your vertex-shader to your shader-program but before you link it (or you have to "relink" it). If you dont specify a location the compiler will do it for you and you can query the location with glGetAttribLocation.